# How do I prevent Internet Explorer to copy all files?

Tags: windows-server-2003, internet-explorer, windows-server-2003-r2

I use Windows Server and often have to download files on the server, but it seems that Internet Explorer copies all files after it completed downloading them. Why this weird behaviour?

It drains the resources heavily, since it copies a gigabyte of data over from the Windows temp directory. It also adds a gigabyte to the vmware thin disk.

The template I use is fully updated, but has not updated to Internet Explorer 8 yet. Will the newest version of Internet Explorer prevent this behaviour? And is there a way I can prevent this download to temp, then copy over style of downloading?

Comment: FWIW, best practice is to not access internet on server itself, but to download files somewhere else and then copy them over to server.

Comment: If you're concerned about the way IE does this why don't you use something more appropriate, such as wget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot prevent IE from downloading to temporary internet files first

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. In IE 9 There is an advanced setting that you can remove the temp files on close. Check the box for `Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed`